# Want to make hyperlinks to html

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I tried to add hyperlink to php but it's not working. Is there any mistakes ?
`

```
echo "<td nowrap ".$rowspan.">\n";
      echo  "<font face=\"arial\" size=\"1\" color=\"#3C5F84\">\n";
      echo  "&nbsp " .$v["refno"].$v["barvalue"]. " &nbsp &nbsp ";
      echo  "</font>\n";
      echo "<a href=\"www.google.com\"></a>\n";
      echo  "</td>\n";
```

`

I tried to add the hyperlink to the current php code but it's not working either when I click.

Comment: Unrelated fyi: `<font>` is deprecated, use CSS instead

Comment: Unrelated: `&nbsp` should be `&nbsp;` and having regular spaces between renders non-breakable spaces useless

Comment: you might also lile to add the `target` attribute to your hyperlinks so that they open in a new window and don't take your visitors away when they click the link - ie: `target='_blank'`

Comment: @brombeer Worse. `<font>` has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) for many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are missing text inside the hyperlink display
2. You need to add http:// in order to visit an external link

So change the line

```
echo "<a href=\"www.google.com\"></a>\n";
```

to

```
echo "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a>\n";
```

So the code will be:

```
<?php
      echo "<table><tr><td nowrap ".$rowspan.">\n";
      echo  "<font face=\"arial\" size=\"1\" color=\"#3C5F84\">\n";
      echo  "&nbsp " .$v["refno"].$v["barvalue"]. " &nbsp &nbsp ";
      echo  "</font>\n";
      echo "<tr><td><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a>\n";
      echo  "</td></table>\n";

?>
```

You may check the following `Sandbox` showing the result (values of $v["refno"] and $v["barvalue"] omitted):

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testSO9Nov2022b.php

Comment: Tysm for the solution. It just works for me.